# Include xml file and associate an activity android

Tags: android, include, android-activity

I have a bottom part of my app that is the same in every activity. So I create an xml file and i included it in each xml file of the activities with

```
<include layout="@layout/menu_bottom"/>
```

then i create a class called Main Activity that extends Activity in which i write this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int res = b.getInt("layout", R.layout.home);

    setContentView(res);

    Button itinerari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.itinerari);

    itinerari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Itinerari.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    Button spostamenti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spostamenti);

    spostamenti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Spostamenti.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    Button mappa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mappa);

    mappa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mappa.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    Button info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);

    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

the problem is that when i start the application i get an error on `int res = b.getInt("layout", R.layout.home);`. It says the problem is `NullPointerException`.

Then if i set manually `setContentView(R.layout.home)` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int res = b.getInt("layout", R.layout.home);
```

`b` may be null (if there is no extra information in intent). So you should check it for `null` value vefore using.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
{
int res = b.getInt("layout", R.layout.home);
}
else
 {
 Log.d("b","Bundle b is null");
 }
```